range-v3 concat and repeat lead to memory access errors
I am using range-v3 and xtensor in my lib to sample data via the following code:
   xarray< T > samples = xt::empty< T >(std::move(samples_shape));

   auto begin = ranges::begin(mask_range);
   auto end_iter = ranges::end(mask_range);
   for(auto&& [i, bounds] : views::enumerate(views::zip(m_start, m_end))) {

      auto [start, end] = bounds;

      auto coordinates = xt::unravel_index(static_cast< int >(i), shape());
      auto index_stride = xt::xstrided_slice_vector(coordinates.begin(), coordinates.end());
      index_stride.emplace_back(xt::all());

      SPDLOG_DEBUG(fmt::format("Strides: {}", index_stride));

      if(begin != end_iter and begin->has_value()) {
         xt::strided_view(samples, index_stride) = xt::random::choice(
            xt::eval(xt::filter(xt::arange(start, end), **begin)), nr_samples, true, rng()
         );
      } else {
         xt::strided_view(samples, index_stride) = xt::random::randint(
            xt::svector{nr_samples}, start, end, rng()
         );
      }
      begin = begin != end_iter ? ranges::next(begin) : end_iter;
   }
   return samples;

This code works fine and runs my tests without fail, take note of the SPDLOG_DEBUG print verifying the correct strides:

Strides: [0, 0, :]
Strides: [0, 1, :]
Strides: [0, 2, :]
Strides: [1, 0, :]
Strides: [1, 1, :]
Strides: [1, 2, :]
Samples:
{{{-4, -5, -3, ..., -5, -4, -4},
{-2,  2,  1, ..., -3, -1, -2},
{ 0, -1,  0, ...,  0, -1,  0}},
{{ 5,  4,  9, ...,  0,  4,  7},
{ 3,  2,  1, ...,  4,  1,  3},
{ 2,  2,  2, ...,  2,  2,  2}}}

However, my handling of the mask_range is a bit clunky, so I wanted to place it inside the zip view as well. Since the mask may be empty (or simply shorter than m_start/m_end), I planned to 'fill it up' by concatenating with an infinite repeat of a nullopt. I have two ways that I try:
a) views::concat(mask_range, views::repeat(std::nullopt))
and
b) views::concat(mask_range, views::repeat(std::optional< xarray< bool > >{std::nullopt})).
with the second being an explicit instantiation of the value_type that mask_range holds.
Using option b) first, the code becomes a little cleaner:
   xarray< T > samples = xt::empty< T >(std::move(samples_shape));

   for(auto&& [i, bounds] : views::enumerate(views::zip(
          m_start,
          m_end,
          views::concat(mask_range, views::repeat(std::optional< xarray< bool > >{std::nullopt}))
       ))) {

      auto [start, end, mask_opt] = bounds;

      auto coordinates = xt::unravel_index(static_cast< int >(i), shape());
      auto index_stride = xt::xstrided_slice_vector(coordinates.begin(), coordinates.end());
      index_stride.emplace_back(xt::all());

      SPDLOG_DEBUG(fmt::format("Strides: {}", index_stride));

      if(mask_opt.has_value()) {
         xt::strided_view(samples, index_stride) = xt::random::choice(
            xt::eval(xt::filter(xt::arange(start, end), *mask_opt)), nr_samples, true, rng()
         );
      } else {
         xt::strided_view(samples, index_stride) = xt::random::randint(
            xt::svector{nr_samples}, start, end, rng()
         );
      }
   }
   return samples;

Now, this version runs into seemingly undefined behaviour which I am unable to explain. Compiling and running throws:

Strides: [-616950173, -1, :]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6:SIGABRT)

-fsanitize=undefined shows the following output:

Strides: [382421549, 1, :]
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL

with the undefined behaviour sanitizer highlighting mask_opt.has_value() in the line:
if(mask_opt.has_value())

with the message Load of value 8, which is not a valid value for type 'bool'
Using option a) and adding address sanitizer to the mix points now to this line being problematic:
auto [start, end, mask_opt] = bounds;

with the message Load of value 160, which is not a valid value for type 'bool'. I don't quite know what to do with this information though.
For further info, in my test cast we have

T = int
mask_range_t = std::array< std::optional< xarray< bool > >, 0 > (0-length array as default parameter for the mask_range argument.

and using clang-16 with c++20 mode.
Frankly, I hope a ranges/range-v3 expert can explain:

Why does option a) even compile? Does range-v3 promote std::nullopt_t to the jointly constructible std::optional< xarray< bool > >?
Is my usage of views::concat/repeat or where does this code go wrong?

EDIT: Here is a reproducing example: Godbolt and here the code on godbolt:
#include <span>
#include <xtensor/xarray.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xrandom.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xstrided_view.hpp>

#include <ranges>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xrandom.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xview.hpp"

template < typename T >
using xarray = xt::xarray< T, xt::layout_type::row_major >;

const auto shape = xt::svector< int >{2, 3};
auto m_start = xarray< int >{{-5, -4, -1}, {0, 0, 2}};
auto m_end = xarray< int >{{-2, 4, 1}, {10, 5, 3}};

template <
   std::integral T = int,
   typename MaskRange = std::array< std::optional< xarray< bool > >, 0 > >
auto sample_broken(size_t nr_samples, const MaskRange& mask_range = {}) -> xarray< T >
{
   using namespace ranges;
   if(nr_samples == 0) {
      throw std::invalid_argument("`nr_samples` argument has to be greater than 0.");
   }
   auto samples_shape = shape;
   samples_shape.push_back(static_cast< int >(nr_samples));
   
   xarray< T > samples = xt::empty< T >(std::move(samples_shape));

   for(auto&& [i, bounds] : views::enumerate(views::zip(
          m_start,
          m_end,
          views::concat(mask_range, views::repeat(std::nullopt))
       ))) {
      auto [start, end, mask_opt] = bounds;

      auto coordinates = xt::unravel_index(static_cast< int >(i), shape);
      auto index_stride = xt::xstrided_slice_vector(coordinates.begin(), coordinates.end());
      index_stride.emplace_back(xt::all());

      if(mask_opt.has_value()) {
         xt::strided_view(samples, index_stride) = xt::random::choice(
            xt::eval(xt::filter(xt::arange(start, end), *mask_opt)), nr_samples, true
         );
      } else {
         xt::strided_view(samples, index_stride) = xt::random::randint(
            xt::svector{nr_samples}, start, end
         );
      }
   }
   return samples;
}


template <
   std::integral T = int,
   typename MaskRange = std::array< std::optional< xarray< bool > >, 0 > >
auto sample_working(size_t nr_samples, const MaskRange& mask_range = {}) -> xarray< T >
{
   using namespace ranges;
   if(nr_samples == 0) {
      throw std::invalid_argument("`nr_samples` argument has to be greater than 0.");
   }
   auto samples_shape = shape;
   samples_shape.push_back(static_cast< int >(nr_samples));
  
   xarray< T > samples = xt::empty< T >(std::move(samples_shape));

   auto begin = ranges::begin(mask_range);
   auto end_iter = ranges::end(mask_range);
   for(auto&& [i, bounds] : views::enumerate(views::zip(m_start, m_end))) {

      auto [start, end] = bounds;

      auto coordinates = xt::unravel_index(static_cast< int >(i), shape);
      auto index_stride = xt::xstrided_slice_vector(coordinates.begin(), coordinates.end());
      index_stride.emplace_back(xt::all());

      if(begin != end_iter and begin->has_value()) {
         xt::strided_view(samples, index_stride) = xt::random::choice(
            xt::eval(xt::filter(xt::arange(start, end), **begin)), nr_samples, true
         );
      } else {
         xt::strided_view(samples, index_stride) = xt::random::randint(
            xt::svector{nr_samples}, start, end
         );
      }
      begin = begin != end_iter ? ranges::next(begin) : end_iter;
   }
   return samples;
}


int main()
{
   xt::random::seed(0);
   auto samples = sample_broken(1000);
//   auto samples = sample_working(1000);
   std::cout << samples;
}


If you comment out sample_broken in main and uncomment sample_working you are no longer given a segfault.

Can you provide a [mcve]? It's difficult to understand this question, especially with all of the undefined names here and the extraneous code.

@Barry, I added a minimal example now. Sorry that it took me a while to get it compiled!

https://godbolt.org/z/vhxKT9nfM

I think this is problem caused by for loop and temporaries in expression. I think in C++23 (or 26) this kind of issue has been addressed. Problem is this line for(auto&& [i, bounds] : views::enumerate(views::zip......

This is not that, I've expanded temporaries and it didn't resolved issue :/ Crash still happens at auto [start, end, mask_opt] = bounds; stack-use-after-scope

Just to clarify, for a moment I've suspected this issue: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2021/05/22/the-subtle-dangers-of-temporaries-in-for-loops/ In C++23 there is change in lifetime of temporaries to addresses this issue.
